# How to split a square matrix into cubes without loops

Tags: r, matrix

I'm struggling to split a matrix without using loops. I want to split a 9x9 matrix into nine 3x3 matrices (not overlaping). I tried using `split()` passing a vector as the "factor" grouping without success. Also tried using `asplit()` without success. I think I don't understand how "MARGIN" works on `asplit()`. I can get the 3x3 "cubes" using loops, but I'm just wondering if there's a way to do it with simple utility functions.

```r
m <- matrix(1:81, 9, 9)
```

I want to store the 9 resulting 3x3 matrices in a list. The expected result for first cube is:

```r
cube[[1]]

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   01   10   19
[2,]   02   11   20
[3,]   03   12   21
```

I tried

```
# all these split by row
indices <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
cubes <- split(m, as.vector(indices))

indices <- array(1:9, dim = c(3, 3, 9))
cubes <- split(m, as.vector(indices))

indices <- array(matrix(1:9, 3, 3), dim = c(3, 3, 9))
cubes <- split(m, as.vector(indices))

# this gives an error
asplit(m, MARGIN = c(3,1))
```

Comment: Have you looked into `array` or `as.array`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a function `as.blockmatrix` in package `blockmatrix` that does this. Although the function is written in base R and uses for-loops

```
 blockmatrix::as.blockmatrix(m, 3,3)
```

---

If you want to use base R, you could write your own function as follows:

```
blocks <- function(x, nr, nc){
  c(tapply(x, list((row(x) - 1)%/%nr, (col(x) -  1)%/%nc), array, c(nr, nc)))
}

blocks(m, 3, 3)
```

---

#### EDIT:

playing around with `aperm` was able to get the below code to work:

```
c(asplit(aperm(array(m, c(3,3,3,3)), c(1,3,4,2)), 3:4))
```

Comment: Thank you @Onyambu your edit with `aperm` is superb! It opened up a whole new world of array possibilities for me.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the most efficient way, but it should work

```r
## utility function to assign (1,2,3) -> 1, (4,5,6) -> 2, etc.
f <- function(x) (x-1) %/% 3 + 1
## create factor from (row-block, col-block) interaction
g <- interaction(f(row(m)), f(col(m)))
## split and convert back to matrices
lapply(split(m, g), \(x) matrix(x, nrow = 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

The input from the question is shown in the Note at the end.  First create a 3x3 matrix containing 1 to 9, `m9`, and a 3x3 matrix of ones, `ones`. The Kronecker product of those two is a block matrix whose first block is all 1's, second block is all 2's and so on.  Split on that and then reform the components into 3x3 matrices.

```
m9 <- matrix(1:9, 3)
ones <- matrix(1, 3, 3)
out <- lapply(split(m, m9 %x% ones), matrix, 3)

str(out)
```

giving

```
List of 9
 $ 1: int [1:3, 1:3] 1 2 3 10 11 12 19 20 21
 $ 2: int [1:3, 1:3] 4 5 6 13 14 15 22 23 24
 $ 3: int [1:3, 1:3] 7 8 9 16 17 18 25 26 27
 $ 4: int [1:3, 1:3] 28 29 30 37 38 39 46 47 48
 $ 5: int [1:3, 1:3] 31 32 33 40 41 42 49 50 51
 $ 6: int [1:3, 1:3] 34 35 36 43 44 45 52 53 54
 $ 7: int [1:3, 1:3] 55 56 57 64 65 66 73 74 75
 $ 8: int [1:3, 1:3] 58 59 60 67 68 69 76 77 78
 $ 9: int [1:3, 1:3] 61 62 63 70 71 72 79 80 81
```

### Note

```
m <- matrix(1:81, 9, 9)
```

Comment: Nice! You could also get the grouping matrix to pass to `split()` by getting the kronecker product. Same thing, just using `kronecker(matrix(1:9, 3, 3), matrix(1, 3, 3))`